# URL to list worksheets does not exist

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to list the worksheets of a given spreadsheet.  I retrieve the list of spreadsheets, and then based on [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/worksheets#retrieve_information_about_worksheets):

> Then examine the `link` element that has
>   `rel="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#tablesfeed"`. That
>   element's `href` value provides the URL for that spreadsheet's
>   worksheets feed.

Thing is, only *some* of the entries returned contain a `link` element with that `rel` attribute.

Manually creating the url to look like the ones that *are* provided doesn't work either:
`https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/KEY/tables`

How do you list the worksheets for spreadsheets that don't provide a link to the worksheets feed?

Answer (score 0):

Google's documentation regarding which feed URL's to GET and POST to are incorrect.  Their examples of XML responses are also incorrect.

To get a list of worksheets for a given spreadsheet [The documentation says](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/index#retrieving_information_about_worksheets_1):

> To determine the URL of a given spreadsheet's worksheets feed, find
>   that spreadsheet's entry in the spreadsheets feed, as described in the
>   previous section. Then examine the `link` element that has
>   `rel="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#tablesfeed"`. That
>   element's `href` value provides the URL for that spreadsheet's
>   worksheets feed.

The correct URL is actually in the `content` `src` attribute of the entry you're after.  It will look something like this:

```
<content type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/tNXTXMh83yMWLVJfEgOWTvQ/private/full"/>
```

Same goes for when you're ready to add a list row to a worksheet.  [The documentation says](http://Then%20determine%20the%20appropriate%20URL%20to%20send%20the%20entry%20to,%20known%20as%20the%20POST%20URL.%20You%20can%20find%20the%20POST%20URL%20in%20the%20list%20feed's%20link%20element%20that%20has%20rel=%22http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post%22.):

> Then determine the appropriate URL to send the entry to, known as the
>   POST URL. You can find the POST URL in the list feed's `link` element
>   that has `rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post"`.

This to is false.  The URL you're after is once again in the `content` `src` attribute of the worksheet entry.  The XML example shows:

```
<content type="text">Sheet1</content>
```

But the actual XML you'll receive looks more like:

```
<content type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1mUjTRGP2ZKyNxBO-rOlqCDlDAsalfElTlzGPnYMSp2c/private/full"/>
```